# How to disable Angular Material Expansion Panel animations?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to disable the animation when you click on the expansion panel?
I tried this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-header {
    transition: none !important; 
}
```

and also this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-body {
    transition: none !important; 
}
```

But none are working for me, animation is still here.

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    Settings
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    Some content
<mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: @Chellappan "How to disable Angular Material Expansion Panel animations?"

Comment: What's your issue exactly? Can you create a StackBlitz Demo to demonstrate what you're trying to reach?

Comment: @k.vincent i just want to get rid off the animation when you click on expansion panel, that's all

Comment: I'am not 100% sure if I understand which animation you mean, but if you want to deactivate open/close panel, then use `<mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="isDisabled" [expanded]="true">...</mat-expansion-panel>` and add a property `isDisabled = true;` in your `*.component.ts`

Comment: @k.vincent dude you know what does animation mean? i want to deactivate the animation when the panel is clicked, ANIMATION, not entire panel

Comment: Open/Close could also be a kind of. Any way, try this: `transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;`

Comment: @k.vincent you can check this animation here: https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples, i am talking about this 'resizing'

Answer (score 23):

**Update 2020-10-16:**

[@.disabled]=true won't work any more - based on response from Angular issue tracker (https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20768):

> ...we changed the expansion panel from using Angular animations to
> using plain CSS animations...

I think the proper approach now would be to add the following styles to your global `styles.css` files (or scope them as needed):

```
mat-expansion-panel,
mat-expansion-panel * {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

Like here (based on the sample by Benjamin):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-10-lgagfp?file=src/styles.scss

**Old answer:**

You can add

```
[@.disabled]="true"
```

binding to your *<mat-expansion-panel>* element to disable animations for the given panel.

Read more here:
https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger#disabling-animations

Comment: You saved my day buddy, Thanks to you.

Comment: How would you do to modify the speed of the animation and not disable it? For example, make it slower

Comment: Great answer. What a performance improvement after disable animation

Comment: This seems to be broken with Angular 10 but worked in Angular 9: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20768

Answer (score 1):

This worked to me <mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="'true'">

Comment: this disables the panel not the animation

Answer (score -5):

Expansion panels can be disabled using the disabled attribute. A disabled expansion panel can't be toggled by the user, but can still be manipulated programmatically.

```
<mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="true">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    Settings
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    Some content
<mat-expansion-panel>
```

Just add `[disabled]="condition"` in `<mat-expansion-panel>` tag

info taken from oficial documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview

Comment: I downvoted this answer because the question was about disabling expansion panel animations, not the expansion panel itself.